# Eigenvalues of the products of a fixed unitari matrix with  diagonal unitari matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gr.group-theory

How does the spectra of $DU$ change when $D$ runs over all diagonal unitary matrices? Here $U$ is a fixed unitary matrix. Precisely, let spec$(X)$ be a set of eigenvalues of $X$.
For a unitary matrix $U$ let 
$$
S_U=\{ \mbox{spec}(DU)\;|\;D\mbox{ runs over all diagonal unitary matrices}\}.
$$ 
Clearly, $S_U$ depends on $U$. Two examples:

1. if $U$ is diagonal then spec($DU$) run over all
   possibilities: $S_U=({\mathbb C}_1)^n$, where ${\mathbb C}_1$ is the set of complex numbers of norm $1$ and $n$ is the size of $U$.
2. Let $U$ be a cyclic permutation, that is
   $$
   U=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} 0 & 0 & 0\dots\dots & 1\\\
                         1 & 0 & 0\dots\dots & 0\\\
                         0 & 1  & 0\dots\dots & 0\\\
                 \dots & \dots & \dots\dots\dots &\dots \\\  
   \end{array}\right).
   $$
   Then $S_U=\{\{wa,w^2a,w^3a,...,w^na\}\;\;|\;\;a\in{\mathbb C}_1,\;w \mbox{ is primitive root of 1}\}$

Is something known about $S_U$ in general?

What is $S_U$ for

a) random $U$

b)for which $U$ $S_U$ looks like in example 2.

c) some concrete $U$, say $U$ being a finite Fourier transform matrices?

Comment: How are you ordering your eigenvalues ? 

Comment: @ Michael I have not notice your comment before. I just consider it as a set... About b). Let $n$ be "very large" Then in example 2)
al matrices $DU$ have  "very small" spectral gaps. So, the question: for which $U$ all $DU$  have small maximal spectral gap? 

As $\\{DU\\}$ may be considered as a point in the flag manifold, one could try to relate this gap with a Reimann distance on the flag manifold....